# micro-service: Zuul & consul require authentification

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, consul

I'm trying to create a Spring cloud microservice application using Zuul and Consul.

I have 2 components in my project:

1. api-gateway microservice using Zuul
2. Hello world microservice (a simple hello world Rest Webservice)

Here is the code of The api-gateway:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableZuulProxy
 @EnableDiscoveryClient
 public class ZuulApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ZuulApplication.class, args);
  }

 }
```

The pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.M3</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.cloud.consul.version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.cloud.consul.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.consul.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    hello1:
     path: /hello1/**
     serviceId: microservice-example

logging:
  level:
   org.springframework: INFO
   com.netflix: DEBUG
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: edge-server

 cloud:
   consul:
    config:
      enabled: true
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
```

Here is the code of hello microservice:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableConfigServer
 @EnableDiscoveryClient
 @RestController
 public class Application {

 @RequestMapping(value="/hello1",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String hello() {
    System.out.print("hello1");
    return "Hello1";
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
 }
}
```

bootstrap.yml:
   spring:
     application:
       name: microservice-example
     profiles:
       active: native

```
 cloud:
  consul:
   config:
    enabled: true
    host: localhost
    port: 8500
```

But, when I test my service the browser requires authentication.

[image]

Comment: Well of course it does, you have Spring Security on the classpath thus it will be automatically configured.

Comment: Thanks for your apply. when I remove sepring security dependency I have this error: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Nov 25 14:21:51 CET 2015

Comment: It should tell you an error code, probably 404 or 500. Looking at your config you likely need to hit http://localhost/hello1/hello1

Comment: Now it's work but I dont understand  why we need to add another hello1 to uri?

Comment: That's the way the proxy works the path you configured `path: /hello1/**` is stripped when it makes the request unless you configure `stripPrefix=false`. So either /hello1/hello1 or add `stripPrefix=false`.

Comment: @spencergibb: when I Enable HTTPS in Spring Boot server consul couldn't check health of service. ani got this error: gent: http request failed 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.dsk.eur.msd.world.xxxxxx:1235/health'.