# Spring cloude: Zuul & consul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, consul

I'm trying to create a Spring cloud microservice application using Zuul and Consul.

I have 2 components in my project:

1. api-gateway microservice using Zuul
2. Hello world microservice (a simple hello world Rest Webservice)

Here is the code of The api-gateway:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableZuulProxy
 @EnableDiscoveryClient
 public class ZuulApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ZuulApplication.class, args);
  }

 }
```

The pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.M3</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.cloud.consul.version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.cloud.consul.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.consul.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    hello1:
     path: /hello1/**
     serviceId: microservice-example

logging:
  level:
   org.springframework: INFO
   com.netflix: DEBUG
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: edge-server

 cloud:
   consul:
    config:
      enabled: true
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
```

Here is the code of hello microservice:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableConfigServer
 @EnableDiscoveryClient
 @RestController
 public class Application {

 @RequestMapping(value="/hello1",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String hello() {
    System.out.print("hello1");
    return "Hello1";
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
 }
}
```

bootstrap.yml:
   spring:
     application:
       name: microservice-example
     profiles:
       active: native

```
 cloud:
  consul:
   config:
    enabled: true
    host: localhost
    port: 8500
```

But, when I test my service the browser shows this message:

[image]

Here is the stacktrace of edge-server application:

```
2015-11-25 16:49:31.780 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7]    c.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper  : Path = null
2015-11-25 16:49:31.781 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper  : Transfer-Encoding = null
2015-11-25 16:49:31.781 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper  : Content-Encoding = null
2015-11-25 16:49:31.781 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper  : Content-Length header = -1
2015-11-25 16:49:31.782 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.n.loadbalancer.ZoneAwareLoadBalancer   : Zone aware logic disabled or there is only one zone
2015-11-25 16:49:31.782 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.n.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext     : microservice-example using LB returned Server: FR09248851D:1234 for request 
2015-11-25 16:49:31.783 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.niws.client.http.RestClient  : RestClient sending new Request(GET: ) http://FR09248851D:1234
2015-11-25 16:49:31.783 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.n.http4.MonitoredConnectionManager     : Get connection: {}->http://FR09248851D:1234, timeout = 2000
2015-11-25 16:49:31.783 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool    : [{}->http://FR09248851D:1234] total kept alive: 1, total issued: 0, total allocated: 1 out of 200
2015-11-25 16:49:31.783 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool    : Getting free connection [{}->http://FR09248851D:1234][null]
2015-11-25 16:49:31.783 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.http4.NFHttpClient           : Stale connection check
2015-11-25 16:49:31.784 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.http4.NFHttpClient           : Attempt 1 to execute request
2015-11-25 16:49:31.791 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.http4.NFHttpClient           : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2015-11-25 16:49:31.796 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.n.http4.MonitoredConnectionManager     : Released connection is reusable.
2015-11-25 16:49:31.796 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool    : Releasing connection [{}->http://FR09248851D:1234][null]
2015-11-25 16:49:31.796 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool    : Pooling connection [{}->http://FR09248851D:1234][null]; keep alive indefinitely
2015-11-25 16:49:31.796 DEBUG 9876 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool    : Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2015-11-25 16:49:35.721 DEBUG 9876 --- [service-example] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : LoadBalancer:  PingTask executing [1] servers configured
2015-11-25 16:49:35.885 DEBUG 9876 --- [clean up thread] com.netflix.http4.ConnectionPoolCleaner  : Connection pool clean up started for client microservice-example
2015-11-25 16:49:35.885 DEBUG 9876 --- [clean up thread] c.n.http4.MonitoredConnectionManager     : Closing expired connections
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [micro-service: Zuul & consul require authentification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915060/micro-service-zuul-consul-require-authentification)